# Can SCOM 2007 and SCCM 2012 co-exist?

Tags: sccm, scom

One of our client's has an existing SCOM 2007 installation, with monitoring agents pushed out to all the Windows servers in their environment. They're now looking at installing SCCM 2012.

What I can't establish is:

- Can SCOM 2007 and SCCM 2012 agents co-exist on the same machine?
- Are there any issues or considerations required in having SCOM 2007 and SCCM 2012 installed on the same network (not on the same server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no known issues installing SCOM 2007 and SCCM 2012 agents on the same machines. It is even possible to use SCCM 2012 to deploy and manager SCOM 2007 agents.

Just don't forget to look at the individual application prerequisites.